# Length of bootstrap to adjust

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I adjust the length of bootstrap buttons without adjusting its width/height? Whenever I adjust the width, It gives me wrong output.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you tried ?

Comment: Mmm... Try `padding` ?

Comment: What do you mean by length? The element is two-dimensions, if you want to adjust one of those dimensions you will have to adjust one of those dimensions (either width or height). Your question does not make any sense.

Comment: What result do you have and which do you want? Please provide some examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "length" but Bootstrap has set sizes for it's buttons

"extra-small", "small", "default" and "large"

as defined by `btn-xs` `btn-sm`, `btn-default` and `bth-lg`

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

However, there is noting to stop you adding your own customer widths by adjusting the left/right padding.

EG.

```
   .btn-wide {
    padding-left: 3em;
    padding-right: 3em;
    }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgjqv0g4/2/)